# "pythonw.exe has stopped working" crashing error after launching anaconda

Tags: python, crash, anaconda, launch

After launching anaconda, python crashes with message "pythonw.exe has stopped working".

[Please find error screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3pTE.png)

I had downloaded some packages(nltk). And after that my anaconda stopped working.
It is giving me **Navigator Error** :

An Unexpected error occurred on Navigator startup 
psutil.AccessDenied(pid=3232)

Tried reinstalling the anaconda,
Also reboot the system,
Fired 'conda update anaconda-navigator' command. 
But does not worked.

Comment: There's not much to go on here, so there isn't much we can do to provide a useful answer. Maybe see if you can find the error logs for python or anaconda and add those to your question.

Comment: I am getting navigator error :
An unexpected error occurred on Navigator start-up psutil.AccessDenied (pid=3232)

I had downloaded some packages . After that my anaconda is not launching.

Answer (score 0):

Access Denied errors usually mean a process is trying to open a file that's already open, or the program doesn't have sufficient permission from Windows to read the particular file.

In this case, it looks like the anaconda-navigator package is having trouble. Look at the python scripts mentioned in the error trace (`start.py`, line 108 and `misc.py`, line 348) and try to find out what file it is trying to open. Then, go to that file in Windows Explorer and give whatever user pythonw.exe is running under (probably your user account, or possibly the Administrators group) permission to read that file. Depending on what navigator's trying to do, it might need write permissions as well. See [here for more info on Windows File permissions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770962(v=ws.11).aspx).